# What is this yellow-orange color bar at the top of Sublime Text?

Tags: sublimetext3, settings, sublimetext

What is this yellow-orange color bar at the top of Sublime Text?

[image: Orange Bar with Yellow Bands]

Hi all,

I've used sublime text before, but last time I used it I think I tinkered with the theme among other things, but I cannot figure out what this orange bar is at the top of the window or how to remove it. I've looked at the documentation but I've had no luck.

TIA

Answer (score 1):

That image is the placeholder image that Sublime uses when a theme references a texture image whose underlying image file can't be found. That can happen if the file is missing or if the `.sublime-theme` file is using the wrong name, for example.

The only way to get rid of it is thus to either:

- Fix the theme to use the correct image name
- Put the missing image in place
- Switch to an alternate theme (e.g. `Default` or `Adaptive`, which ship with Sublime)

If you're using a custom theme it should be an easy thing to check your `sublime-theme` file to see what images it's referencing and compare that to images you've added to the theme package to see what's missing.

The most expedient would be the theme switch to one of the ones that ship with Sublime.

If you're already using one of those two themes and you're having this problem, then the issue is that you're augmenting the existing theme and causing it to break. In that case, there are two things to check.

1. Use `Preferences > Browse Packages` from the menu or command palette; do you see a folder named `Theme - Default`? If so, move it away, the files in it are overriding the default themes (including `Adaptive`; they're both in the same package).
2. Using the same command as above, look in the `User` package; look for `sublime-theme` files and move them away; such files will be combined with other files of the same name, which allows you to add rules to an existing theme in a way that could be breaking it.